# Can a pure external disk be a threat to Ubuntu computer

Tags: ubuntu

I bought a used external disk and now I wonder if any threats can occur from this. Its a disk without casing, so I'am using my own USB adapter. Is there anything else I should take care of when I connect the disk first time?

Iam using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Any secondhand or unverified equipment is an attack vector. From firmware viruses to voltage based attacks, without confirming it's safe you'll never know. That said there are ways to protect yourself that someone will probably put into an answer with more information than I could provide.